# Translation of 権現様: literally or not?

Tags: translation, history

I am reading a book about the life of 国友一貫斎. For reference, the title is 「夢をまことに」. There is the following courtroom scene, in which reference is made to 権現様, a Shinto-Buddhist term for a god. The full sentences are perhaps not needed, but I included it in the second example for context. The story takes place in the early 1800's.

How should these sentences, specifically the part with the word in question be translated? Is it really "we cannot find that the gods have forbidden..." or is it referring to something else, like the court?

> 権現様のころは、。。。
>
> じつは役人達に古い記録を調べさせたが、**権現様**が諸大名の大小鉄炮張り立てを禁止したという法度が出てこなんだ。

I am also curious about the end of the second sentence. Is believe it is a shortening of こんなんだ, as in 来ないのだ。

Comment: This 権現様 is probably [Tokugawa Ieyasu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokugawa_Ieyasu), aka 東照大**権現** （とうしょうだいごんげん）.

Comment: @marasai Aha, that would explain it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the 新明解{しんめいかい}国語{こくご}辞典{じてん}, the term 権現{ごんげん} refers to a bodhisattva, an avatar of the Buddha, or a Japanese god as a manifestation of a buddha in Shintoism. 徳川{とくがわ}家康{いえやす}, the founder of the Tokugawa Shogunate, was worshipped and called 権現様{ごんげんさま} or 東照{とうしょう}権現{ごんげん} by people.

So the line you quoted is translated as follows;

> In the time of Gongen-sama (the Lord, Iyeyasu)…
>   In fact, I had the bureaucrats check the old records, but no regulations to prohibit the storage of cannons and guns were found.

"出てこなんだ" is an old way of saying “出てこなかった,” meaning “It didn’t come out.”

Comment: Thanks! One question about your translation, 張り立て means the making of guns, right, not their storage?

Comment: @Espen Nielsen. In fact, I'm not sure. I checked both　新明解国語辞典 and 広辞苑, both of which doesn't carry 張りたて as a heading. I assume it's either a production or storage. I took the latter, but it can be production either.

Comment: Eirikr Ultendir. Thank you for your editing to make my answer easier to read. However, there’s one shortcoming in your take. Bodhisattva isn’t an avatar of Buddha. A bodhisattva is one who strive to become a Buddha – 覚者, an awaken man to the truth of universe. Buddha and Bodhisattva are not on the same stage spiritual enlightenment.

Comment: @YoichiOishi, yes, I agree about bodhisattva vs. buddha.  I understood your post (and references) to mean that 権現 = 1) a bodhisattva, 2) an avatar of the Buddha, or 3) a Japanese _kami_ as a manifestation of a buddha.  Was that your intention?  If not, I apologize for my confusion and ask for further clarification.

Comment: Erikr Utlendi. I rechecked 新明解国語辞典. It says 権現 means the appearance of Budda and Bodhisattvas in transformed form of (one of )Japanese God(s). So it can be a metamorphosis of either Buddha or a Boddhisattva. In other word, 德川家康 was believed to have become "a god" after his death by populace in Edo era. By the way, it's Shintoisms' theory that everyone becomes "a god" after his / her death. See millions gods enshrined in the Yasukuni Shrine.